# Angularjs summernote throwing $parse syntax error with Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, angularjs, summernote

I am getting a parse error with using ng-int directive  in angularjs summernote.
here is the code:

```
           <summernote name="template_content" ng-model="document.template_content" ng-       init="document.template_content='{{$documentTemplate->content}}'" height="500">  </summernote>
```

What I am trying to do is ng-init directive to intialize the ngModel with the laravel variable data. However, I am getting a error saying

> Syntax Error: Token 'Times' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].

Here is value that I am trying to display in the summernote 'Promissory Note

J$ 500,000.00'

What could be the cause of me getting this error and not showing the information in the summernote directive ngModel?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post rendered HTML for this tag?

Comment: Just added the HTML that needs to be rendered

Comment: You need to check rendered HTML seen in page source. the problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

**ngInit** accepts a logic statement, not an expression. So you shouldn't be using any `{{}}` interpolation syntax. Try this.

```
ng-init="document.template_content=$documentTemplate.content"
```

Comment: `{{$documentTemplate->content}}` is Laravel templating tag, server side.